# How to find the nearest and the larger from a list of dates?

Tags: c#

Given a start date, how do I find the larger and nearest start date from a list?

Here's my code but my way of getting the nearest one seems to be incorrect:

```
Activity oActivityNearestLarger = null;

List<Activity> oActivityByStartDateList = ClassForDBCalls.ActivityLISTByOutingID(iOutingID)
    .OrderBy(a => a.StartDate)
    .ToList();

long lLeastTicksDifference = 0; // initialize
int iIndexOfTheNearestLargerActivity = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < oActivityByStartDateList.Count; i++)
{
    // the start of the loop, set the lRecordTicksDifference
    if (i == 0)
    {
        lLeastTicksDifference = Math.Abs(oActivityByStartDateList[0].StartDate.Value.Subtract(dtStartDate).Ticks);
    }

    long lCurrentTicksDifference = Math.Abs(oActivityByStartDateList[i].StartDate.Value.Subtract(dtStartDate).Ticks);

    // get the larger, closest start datetime in the activities for the outing
    if (oActivityByStartDateList[i].StartDate > dtStartDate)
    {
        //  is the current activity startdate closer 
        //  to the to be added startdate (is it the nearest to the datetime being added?)
        if (lCurrentTicksDifference <= lLeastTicksDifference)
        {
            // if it has the least difference (meaning closer) store it for comparison in the next iteration
            lLeastTicksDifference = lCurrentTicksDifference;

            oActivityNearestLarger = oActivityByStartDateList[i];

            // set the index to be used to determine the Activity previous to it
            iIndexOfTheNearestLargerActivity = i;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will this not do it?

```
Activity nearestToStart = 
    lassForDBCalls.ActivityLISTByOutingID(iOutingID)
    .OrderBy(a => a.StartDate)
    .FirstOrDefault(a => a.StartDate >= myStartDate)
```

Or am I missing something?

**Sorry, just saw how dumb that first attempt was**

```
Activity nearestToStart = 
    lassForDBCalls.ActivityLISTByOutingID(iOutingID)
    .Where(a => a.StartDate >= myStartDate)
    .OrderBy(a => a.StartDate)
    .FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: 20K? Congrats, pile on a few more! <Joel>Bored enough in your job to answer LINQ questions? Go to SO careers!</Joel> :P

Comment: @Ruben: What I'm doing now involves lots of long builds. Work/build cycles are long enough to get bored, but not long enough to get stuck into something else, so sue me if I took some time to answer a few questions! The "answer questions hunger" will be gone off me now I've hit this milestone :)

Comment: Excuses excuses is all I say :D

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the list to find the dates greater than `dtStartDate` and then order it and take the first one, that is the *larger and nearest start date*.

```
var result = oActivityByStartDateList.Where(x => x.StartDate > dtStartDate).OrderBy(x => x.StartDate).First();
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
var startDateList = ClassForDBCalls.ActivityLISTByOutingID(iOutingID);

oActivityNearestLarger = startDateList
    .Where(a => a.StartDate > dtStartDate)
    .OrderBy(a => a.StartDate).First();
```

Comment: @ChrisF what about them? Not part of the OP as far as I can tell

Comment: Oops - my mistake. Comment withdrawn. I was confused by his use of `Abs` when getting the difference.

Answer (score 0):

I think you also need to check whether the largest date is later than datetime.now.
nearest will give the closest date to today even if it is earlier than today.

```
DateTime nearest = oActivityByStartDateList.OrderBy(q => Math.Abs((q.StartDate - DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds)).First().StartDate;
     DateTime largest = oActivityByStartDateList.Where(p => p.StartDate.CompareTo(DateTime.Now) > 0).OrderByDescending(p => p.StartDate).First().StartDate;
```