# get the next date from a list closer to today in c#

Tags: c#, wpf, list, date

I need to pick from a list the next available date ( if exists ) .
If for example I have a list with three dates , namely 12 December 2015 , 3 March 2016 and 25 April 2016, and today is 25 January 2016 .
How can I recover only next to the date today ? calculating that unordered lists and I have to retrieve the record next to the current date .

Thank you

Comment: So in this example you would like to get 3th March 2016?

Comment: yes in this example 3th March 2016

Comment: Write down the math on paper, then write it in code. The trivial way would be to sort the list based on ABS(milliseconds from now), for example, and take the first result.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? A [mcve] showing the basic setup and how far you've got would help a lot. Hint: if you sort the list, then filter anything before today, it'll be really simple...

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "next to the date today"? Can it be in the past, or do you only want future dates?

Comment: I ordered list , but a bubble sort or like me become very slow , if there is a method of the framework that already does this , and someone in the know it you'll be very happy

Comment: @JonSkeet only future and single next date

Comment: Can you anyway please read [ask] and share your research? [Find next closest date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22208245/find-next-closest-date), [Find the closest time from a list of times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757136/find-the-closest-time-from-a-list-of-times), [How to find the nearest and the larger from a list of dates?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10314156/how-to-find-the-nearest-and-the-larger-from-a-list-of-dates) and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the comments this should work for you:

```
List<DateTime> dt;
dt.Sort((a, b) => a.CompareTo(b)); // If your list isnt sorted.
var greaterThanNow = dt.SkipWhile(x => x <= DateTime.Now).First();
```

You said it gives you the last element (which in your mind isnt correct). So here's a full example:

```
List<DateTime> dt = new List<DateTime>()
{
    new DateTime(2016, 01, 20),
    new DateTime(2016, 02, 10)
};
dt.Sort((a, b) => a.CompareTo(b)); // If your list isnt sorted.
var greaterThanNow = dt.SkipWhile(x => x <= DateTime.Now).First();
```

This will return `10.02.2016 00:00:00`.

```
List<DateTime> dt = new List<DateTime>()
{
    new DateTime(2016, 01, 20),
    new DateTime(2016, 01, 05)
};
dt.Sort((a, b) => a.CompareTo(b)); // If your list isnt sorted.
var greaterThanNow = dt.SkipWhile(x => x <= DateTime.Now).First();
```

This will give you `InvalidOperationException`.

```
List<DateTime> dt = new List<DateTime>()
{
    new DateTime(2016, 01, 20),
    new DateTime(2016, 01, 05)
};
dt.Sort((a, b) => a.CompareTo(b)); // If your list isnt sorted.
var greaterThanNow = dt.SkipWhile(x => x <= DateTime.Now).FirstOrDefault();
```

This will return `01.01.0001 00:00:00`.

---

I guess this should be enough to continue working.

Comment: i have try this solution but i get the 4th march 2016, is the last element of the list

Comment: Is the Sort function better than OrderBy? e.g.

`var greaterThanNow = dt.OrderBy(d => d).SkipWhile(x => x <= DateTime.Now).First();`

Comment: @LordJam: Not according the topic but take a look in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832684/c-sharp-sort-and-orderby-comparison